# Function pointer demo

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

Check the below code

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

void functionptrdemo()
{
    typedef int *(funcPtr) (int,int);
    funcPtr ptr;
    ptr = add; //IS THIS CORRECT?
    int p = (*ptr)(2,3);
    cout<<"Addition value is "<<p<<endl;
}
```

In the place where I try to assign a function to function ptr with same function signature, it shows a compilation error as **error C2659: '=' : function as left operand**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is very likely that what you intended to write was not:

```
typedef int *(funcPtr) (int,int);
```

but:

```
typedef int (*funcPtr) (int,int);
```

Comment: @sbi: I tried it immediately. But the site didn't allow me to accept the answer with in 5 minutes :)

Comment: @AKN: I'm sorry I was so impatient. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Alex answer is correct. 
But the good practice will be

```
ptr = &add;
```

if you write like this below:

```
ptr = add;
```

it is the compiler which assumes that you wanted 
to store the address of the function add.
So better let's not make the compiler to assume.

Comment: there is no assumption functions can only be stored as pointers

Comment: Why?  It's not as if there's any ambiguity.  Do you also avoid implicit decay of arrays to pointers and use `&array[0]` instead of `array`?  And do you invoke function pointers via `(*func)(arg)`?